# Django ManyToManyField error when trying to pull values from other models

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm trying to recreate Groupon using purely django and have having trouble with the below. This is my below idea

1. A Merchant can start a Campaign(which has a unique CampaignID)
2. A Customer(who has his own unique ID) can save a Campaign to be redeemed later

I created a model with 3 columns (CampaignID, CustomerID and a booleanfield with a default value of False)

```
class Customer_save(models.Model):

    Customer_ID = models.ManyToManyField(Customer)
    Campaign_ID = models.ManyToManyField(Campaigns)
    Redeemed = models.BooleanField(default = False) #False denotes that it hasnt been redeemed yet

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Customer_ID.username,self.Campaign_ID.Campaign_desc
```

I'm trying to create a fake a row wanting to test if everything properly gets fed into the table. But i'm coming across errors. Could you please tell me where i'm going wrong?

```
Campaign_ID = '10001'
Customer_ID = 'C12345'

    Customer_save.add(Customer_ID = Customer_ID,Campaign_ID = Campaign_ID)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: type object 'Customer_wallet' has no attribute 'add'
```

---

```
>>> New = Customer_save(Customer_ID = Customer_ID, Campaign_ID `=Campaign_ID)`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/kj/Desktop/projects/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 480, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
```

---

```
>>> new = Customer_save.Customer_ID.create(Customer_ID = Customer_ID)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'create'
TypeError: 'Customer_ID' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: please read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the relevant records before assigning them to a many-to-many field:

```
customer = Customer(...)
customer.save()
campaign = Campaigns(...)
campaign.save()
customer_save = Customer_save(Redeemed=...)
customer_save.save()
customer_save.Customer_ID.add(customer)
customer_save.Campaign_ID.add(campaign)
```

More information on [Django documentation: Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

PS. I would recommend you to choose better names for your fields and models and follow the [formal style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). They are a bit misleading and often such names lead to confusion, never mind that it is difficult for others to follow your code.